The MOSFET of H-bridge Inverter always explode
I met some difficulties these days.
I use 4 MOSFETs to put on a H-bridge inverter which output power is 1300 W. The dc input of inverter is 310-400 V. The Ids of MOSFET is 80 A and the Vds is 650 V. So I think it's enough to build my inverter.
The core of inverter controlling I use STM32F103C8T6 of ST to output PWM, and the gate driver I use IR2110 of Infineon to driving MOSFET. However, the MOSFET will explode as long as the output power more than 300 W. In the process of fix, when cut off the high voltage dc input， I found the output of STM32F103C8T6 is normal

and the IR2110 is same. Conversely, when the high voltage dc input is not be cut, the output of STM32F103C8T6 is like Pic.2

and the output of IR2110 is like Pic.3

it's two driving voltage of a half bridge.
Just like you see, the PWM of MCU and the driving voltage of MOSFET is abnormal because obivous after driving voltage from high to low, it's still exists a short voltage rising and it maybe makes MOSFET to take-on again and the short circuit will happen. But all of these only take when the dc input is put. I guess the reason is MCU is interfered by high voltage input because I used IR2110 which is non-isolated gate driver, so my inverter could not output high power. Of course it is wrong, maybe because I'm just a student.
This is my schematic of controller, I use STM32F103C8T6 to product PWM1~PWM4. And there are input of gate drivers, too.
This is my schematic of gate driver which use IR2110.

This is my H bridge inverter:

This is my PCB layout:

Well, the VDD which left of the D3 and D6 means 15 V DC voltage, and the VDD5 means 5 V DC voltage which is the logical input of U2 and U4.
The VDD is product by the flyback circuit which converts the 310-400V (the input of inverter) to the 15 V DC voltage. 
Then I continue to convert 15 V DC (VDD) to the 5 V DC (VDD5) by using TPS5430, and convert 5 V DC (VDD5) to the 3.3 V DC (VDD3.3) by using AMS1117-3.3V. There are the schematic. However, the ground of inverter (PGND), the ground of the VDD and VDD5 (SGND)，and the ground of VDD3.3 (DGND), I connect them by the 0 Ω resistance.


Welcome! Show your layout and your probe setup.

I could not make heads or tail of "because obivous after driving".

That looks like a miller capacitance issue to me. Right when the fet turns on there is some kind of oscillation. The way I have solved this in the past is to construct the circuit (with parasitics) in LTSpice and experiment with snubbers and gate drive resistance until it's solved.

Sorry sir, I am new here and please forgive my ability of English speaking is weak. it means that you can see the voltage has a transient rising when the voltage changes from high level to low.

Need a schematic an layout

Where is wired VDD (at left of D3 and D6? Where is wired VDD5 (power supply of U2 and U4)?

I agree with Drew that you're looking at the effects of Miller. You need either stronger gate drive or ballast capacitor on your gate to minimize the effect. If the latter, you need to sacrifice gate current into your ballast capacitor.

Is this a VFD by the way?

Mr. Winny, it's Vgs in one of the ways in my inverter.

Mr. Antonio, I have already upload my schematic of how to product VDD and VDD5.

Ok. Note that I remember (??? to be verified) that "only" the HOL and HOR signals need PWM. The other two need only then single signals (high or low).

Well, Mr. Antonio I use STM32 to product 4 pwm, the pwm 1 and pwm 4 there are same, it is same for pwm 2 and pwm 3. It's seeking for trouble for myself now but it should not interfered the output of gate drivers
